# What is happening in the "App" declaration generated by "react-native init"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I do:

```
npx react-native init MyTestApp
```

The `App.js` file that is created includes the line:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

I'm familiar with the arrow syntax for functions, but

1) What is the colon after `App` doing?

2) What is the dollar sign in `React$Node` doing? `React` is imported, but I don't see any variable named `React$Node`, which is what I would expect this to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its type definition from Flow, it means that constant `App` is of type function and it returns `ReactNode.`

ReactNode is one of these types:

```
 ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined
```

This means the function App can return, any valid JSX (in react native its anything from View, Text, .etc), ReactFragment, React.Portal, boolean, null, undefined

If you are confused about the dollar sign, here is a link with explanation. `https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/`

There are separate sections for "private" or "magic" types with a $ in the name. See the note here and comment here. Update: Some these types are now documented here.

For easy you can think of it as its Node from React (think of it as scope/namespace)

This is the best explanation given by Lukas , do feel free to ask any doubts.